# Programmatically communicate with Windows 8 Music Player

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I would like to know if it is possible to programmatically communicate with the default Windows 8 Music Player (Windows store app).
For example, when is it start/finish playing a new song, what is the name of the song etc.

I vaguely have an impression that WinRT app are based on COM/DCOM, so I suspect there maybe a way to expose that to be consume by external program.  Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 1):

Windows store apps are "sandboxed" apps. You can't communicate with other WinRT apps. So you can't access what's being played in Music app of Windows 8 app.

Comment: So, there is no way to perform automation on Windows store app? No way to specifically configure the system to grant permission on those sandbox?

Comment: What kind of automation you want to achieve ? See you CAN create apps which can interact with each other but it depends upon your requirement. But that's fact you can't communicate with default Win8 apps. There's no way to bypass sandboxed environment.

Answer (score 0):

The only way a windows app can communicate with it's host environment is through what is called Activation Protocol which basically opens another app. So metro media players can't provide info about what they are doing to other apps. 
Also a metro app can ask a file to be opened by default handler of host system. 
So the answer is no. There can't be a way for the media player to inform other apps about it's status. 
Windows metro Apps are more similar to a Silverlight app than a COM/DCOM component.